# Progress Dialog causing Virtual Keyboard to not show on WebView

Tags: android, android-webview, virtual-keyboard, customdialog

I have a weirb bug that is pissing me off.
I have an app that is pretty much only a webview with some extra functionalities, one of them is a Custom Loading Dialog (Extended from the progress dialog) that I show on the onPageStarted call, and dismiss on the onPageFinished call. The problem is, if I do that (show the dialog), the virtual keyboard will only show if the user touch TWO times on a form text box (Html or Javascript Text box on the Webview).

- I've tried manually giving focus to the webview, before and after the GUI update by the handler that dismisses the Dialog.
- Redrawing the WebView
- Not showing the dialog (this works, but I need the dialog)

Anyone have an idea on how to fix that?

Thanks!

Comment: (Or at least an workaround, because that is all I am trying right now, btw WEIRD nor weirb, sorry)